# How do I exactly match a record in MySQL using regular expressions?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm making a news system that uses unique slugs to identify the article. When creating a new article, I need to make sure the unique slug is not already in use. So if two articles have the exact same name, they will therefore generate the exact same slug. I want to append a number to the end of the slug in the event it is in use.

Like so:

- some-really-interesting-article
- some-really-interesting-article-1
- some-really-interesting-article-2

And so on. So in my test case, I'm selecting all records from the database that exactly match "some-really-interesting-article" with 0 or more "-number". So in this case I will return 3 rows, so the next slug would be "some-really-interesting-article-3".

This works great except my regex is behaving peculiar (or likely very normal, and I just suck at regex) and is also return rows with partial matches. So if I search "some-really-interesting", that will pass.

```
SELECT id, title, slug
FROM news 
WHERE slug RLIKE '([[:<:]]some-really-interesting-article[[:>:]][-\d]*)'
```

So as I said, if I run the above regex with "some-really-interesting" it will return all 3 rows.

Please tell me that I am blatantly and ignorantly doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is better suited -- unless things have changed, MySQL regex can't use an index so it'll work but could always be faster.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? When I try your regex in 5.1, it works the way you want; i.e., "some-really-interesting" does not pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
"^some-really-interesting-article(-[[:digit:]]+)?$"
```

Hopefully this will work :)

Comment: Aha! Success! Apparently MySQL doesn't like the "\d". I tried ain's pattern with [:digit:] instead of \d and it worked as well. Woot!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE slug RLIKE '(^some-really-interesting-article(-[0-9]+)?$)'
```

Comment: This appears to fix my original problem, however now it only will return "some-really-interesting-article", and none of the ones with "-number" after it.

Comment: I changd the expression after original post, please try again (I think I had an unnessesary \ there).

Comment: I just copy/pasted it exactly as you have it and no dice. It only returns the one row. EDIT: However when I test this pattern outside of MySQL, it works exactly how it should. Hmm.

Comment: Whats the column type, `CHAR(n)` or `VARCHAR(n)`? In case of CHAR there is trailing spaces in the value of the DB field... so try the pattern without the `$` in the end or with something like `(-[\d]+)?[:space:]*$` in the end. Or perhaps use `trim(slug)`

Comment: Trying the pattern without the $ puts me back at the problem in my original post. And the second pattern is the same results as your original pattern. EDIT: And it is a VARCHAR(80), by the way. EDIT 2: I already do use trim($slug) before I insert it.

Comment: Doh, it looks like MySQL doesn't support \d as "digit class marker" so you'd have to use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` instead... see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, this will work:

```sql
SELECT id, title, slug FROM news
WHERE slug RLIKE '^some-really-interesting-article(-[0-9]+)?$'
```

However, MySQL is not smart enough to make good use of indexes with `RLIKE`.  (If you have an index on the `slug` column, it may try to use it, but will have to do a full index scan.)  It turns out, though, that you can use a redundant `LIKE` condition to help MySQL handle the query more efficiently, like this:

```sql
SELECT id, title, slug FROM news
WHERE slug LIKE 'some-really-interesting-article%'
  AND slug RLIKE '^some-really-interesting-article(-[0-9]+)?$'
```

The `LIKE` query might match some false positives, like `some-really-interesting-article-about-something-else-entirely`, but the `RLIKE` will weed them out.  Of course, if you don't care about such false positives, you could leave out the `RLIKE` entirely.

Of course, another possibility would be to create a unique index on the `slug` column (which you really should have anyway) and just keep incrementing the slug and trying to insert the record until the `INSERT` succeeds.  Of course, that also means you should check the error code and message to see why it fails if it does.  (If an `INSERT` fails because of a duplicate value, the [error code](http://php.net/mysql-errno) should be [1062](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry) and the [error message](http://php.net/mysql-error) should contain the name of the duplicate key.)

Anyway, [here an SQLize link](http://www.sqlize.com/EQmMF20IEb) if you want to play with the query; I left some comments in it.